# template doesnt exist "django 2.0"

Tags: django, django-views, django-settings

please can anyone help me  i cant figure out what is the error while rendering template in djano 2.0 
i created a app and and in the views.py section i added all thoe code lines of manange.py imported urls(directly in the views ) tried to run the server (python views.py runserver)

here is my complete code from views.py

```
import os
import sys
from django.conf import settings

DEBUG = os.environ.get('DEBUG', 'on') == 'on'
SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY', os.urandom(32))
ALLOWED_HOSTS = os.environ.get( 'localhost','127.0.0.1').split(',')
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)

settings.configure(
DEBUG=DEBUG,
SECRET_KEY=SECRET_KEY,
ALLOWED_HOSTS=ALLOWED_HOSTS,

ROOT_URLCONF=__name__,
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES=(
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
),
)
INSTALLED_APPS=(
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.auth',
),
TEMPLATE_DIRS=(
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
),
STATICFILES_DIRS=(
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
),
STATIC_URL='/static/',

#############################views & urls###############################s

from django import forms
from django.urls import path,include
from django.core.cache import cache
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseBadRequest
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.decorators.http import etag

# Create your views here.

application = get_wsgi_application()

def home(request):
    return render(request,'index.html')

urlpatterns=[


path('',home,name='home'),

]
######################################   #############################################
if __name__ == "__main__":
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

and i tried placing templates in the same directory where views exist and also in outside of the app folder

i should be getting a basic template as explained in the book lightweight django

instead:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /

index.html

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version:     2.0
Exception Type:     TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    

index.html

Exception Location:     C:\Users\madhumani\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py in get_template, line 19
Python Executable:  C:\Users\madhumani\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe
Python Version:     3.6.2
Python Path:    

['D:\\python\\tempo python\\dajngo rest api\\api\\pi',
 'C:\\Users\\madhumani\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\python36.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\madhumani\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\madhumani\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\madhumani\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32',
 'C:\\Users\\madhumani\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python36\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\madhumani\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\lib\\site-packages']
```

Comment: before, doing something you don't know. read the docs, see the others code and learn.

Answer (score 2):

TEMPLATE_DIRS has not been a supported setting since Django 1.10. You should get a more up to date guide.

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
      'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
      'APP_DIRS': True,
      'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
    },
]
```

(Also, don't put your settings in your views. There's a settings.py file for a reason.)